# Why does the 2D hexagonal lattice have a different tight binding band structure than Graphene?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, graphene, tight-binding

[Here](http://lampx.tugraz.at/~hadley/ss1/bands/tbtable/tbtable.html) you can find band structures for various tight binding models. I was wondering, why the 2-D hexagonal lattice has a different band structure than Graphene, even though they have the same lattice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What they call hexagonal lattice is actually a triangular lattice. 
You can see that there is only one band ins the DOS/ Band structure so in 2D it can only be a rectangular or a triangular lattice.
If you draw several cell of a triangular lattice, you will see appears the hexagonal shape.

EDIT: Actually, the hexagonal lattice refer to the triangular lattice, they are the same thing. The Graphene on the other hand is a **honeycomb** lattice and can be expressed as a hexagonal lattice with two atoms per cell, leading to two bands in the graphene case.

Comment: Why is there in two dimensions only one band? Or what I actually want to ask: How do you know that?

Comment: The number of band depend on the number of states in one unit cell. For the tight-binding of the graphene with one state per atom, the cell is made out of 2 atoms so there is 2 states per cell so there is two bands. This band can touches. This is a direct implication of the Bloch solutions

Comment: The number of band does not depend on the dimension of the system. But only on the number of states per unit cell.